# String format and replace

Tags: vb.net

I  want to change userId to `****`.  I want to count length of a userId and change the string to that many asterisks.  I also want to take the account number and replace all characters except the last 4 `XXXX`.

How do I do these things?

Comment: That totally depends on your data...could you please provide us with some samples? How long cann the Id be? How land is the account number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming accountNumber and userid are strings

```
Dim userid As String = "1234"
Dim accountNumber As String = "1234-5678-9876"

userid = New String("*"c, userid.Length)

accountNumber = New String("X"c, accountNumber.Length - 4) & 
                                                      Right(accountNumber, 4)

MsgBox(userid + vbCrLf + accountNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first one - assuming that your userId is only contains characters A-Z

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("userID", "[A-z]", "*")
```

Comment: what do I do if I want to replace all character in userId not only alpha it can have unserscores numbers or alpha

Comment: change the regular expression `[A-z]` to `\w` which will match A-z 0-9 and _

Comment: There are *other* ways of manipulating strings besides regexes :) `userid = New String("*"c, userid.Length)`